# Job Advertisement related "questions"

Tags: discussion

With the opportunity of [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/looking-for-a-computer-vision-coder-unsure-where-to-seek-canditates?noredirect=1#comment71979_37439), earlier today, I was wondering what the consensus would be for somehow incorporating "job adverts" in DSP SE.

My advice to the OP was to post the job at Stackoverflow and then notify this community (which could be interested in taking up that job) with a post relevant to the problem and a link via the DSP Meta site.

What does everyone think? What would be best practice recommendation for future posts of this kind? Do we need a `job` / `work` related tag?

Comment: it is a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already posted in the comments to that post that Stack Overflow [has its own jobs site.](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)

[Joel Spolsky posted on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-posting-a-job-on-Stack-Overflow-an-effective-way-to-find-solid-programmers/answer/Joel-Spolsky?srid=D9c) (imagine that!) about the efficacy of the SO jobs site: [they offer a money-back guarantee for the job poster.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31643/131640)

So it's probably not a good idea to allow them here; I've not seen it on any of the other SE websites.

I realize that DSP jobs don't necessarily fit into the remit of the SO jobs site... but I think the need is too small for us to consider taking it on here.

Comment: Hi Peter K. I did not think that far ahead. I liked the idea of the SO Jobs website and I thought that "we" might want to think about how to best handle opportunities to not flood the board with low quality "looking for" posts. As for the last sentence, my take would be "Build it and they will come" :)